# Bulk insert test failing for lead convert

Tags: trigger, lead-conversion, bulk

I have an apex trigger helper method that converts lead to contact when certain conditions are met. My bulk insert test method is failing on the line where I assign email to lead. The single insert test is succeeding.

The org uses email to prevent contact duplicates.

Please help me figure out why my bulk insert test is failing? Thanks.

The error is '"System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded" Class.LeadTriggerHelperTest.convertLeadToContactInsertBulkTest: line 98, column 1'

where line 98 is this

l.Email = 'mytest' + count +'@test.com';

```
for(Lead ld : lds){
                String ldEmail = ld.Email;
                String ldId = ld.Id;
                String acctId = ld.InvitedtoBusinessAccountId__c;
                
                
                if(!oldMap.isEmpty()){//Lead update scenario: Check if the Trigger.oldMap is populated to know when an update has taken place
                   
                        if(oldMap.get( ldId ).hasBusinessAccount__c != newMap.get( ldId ).hasBusinessAccount__c && newMap.get( ldId ).hasBusinessAccount__c == true && 
                           oldMap.get( ldId ).InvitedToBusinessAccountId__c != newMap.get( ldId ).InvitedToBusinessAccountId__c && newMap.get( ldId ).InvitedToBusinessAccountId__c != null){
                            if(ldEmail != null){
                                Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
                                lc.setLeadId(ld.Id);
                                lc.setAccountId(ld.InvitedtoBusinessAccountId__c);
                                lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
                                
                                lc.setConvertedStatus(convertedStatus.MasterLabel);
                                Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            
                               
                                String cId = lcr.getContactId();
                                cidList.add(cId) ;

      

                      
                        }
                       else if(ldEmail == null){
                           throw new customException('Email field is required to prevent duplicates');
                       }
                    } 
                
                   
            }
```

My test method that is failing

```
static void convertLeadToContactInsertBulkTest(){
        Map<Id,Lead> emptyMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
        Map<Id,Lead> newMap = new Map<Id,Lead>();
        List<Lead> newLeads = new List<Lead>();
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        
        for(Integer i = 0; i<200 ; i++){
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Name = 'testacc' + i;
            accList.add(a);
        }
        

        insert accList;



        Integer count = 0;
            for(Account a: accList){
                if(a.Name == 'testacc'+ count){
                    String accId = a.Id;
                    Lead l = new Lead();
                    l.LastName = 'test lead' + count;
                    l.Company = 'testacc' + count;
                    l.Email = 'mytest' + count +'@test.com';// the test is failing on this line                    
                    l.DateAddedToBusinessAccount__c = System.now();
                    l.hasBusinessAccount__c = true;
                    l.InvitedtoBusinessAccountId__c = accId;

                    newLeads.add(l);
                    count++;
                }
               
            }
            
        
 
       
        insert newLeads;

        Test.startTest();
        
        LeadTriggerHelper.convertLeadToContact(newLeads, emptyMap, newMap );

        
        List<Contact> bulkContacts = [Select Id from Contact ];
        System.debug('second '+ bulkContacts.size());

        System.assertEquals(200, bulkContacts.size());
        Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: Hi. It would be useful to include the actual error detail as well - you can [edit] the question to add that. I am guessing the issue is a too many DML operations or similar. Take a look at how [Database.convertLead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_convertLead) takes either a single or list of conversions. You seem to be calling it with a single lead, in a loop. You need to refactor the code to use a bulk pattern where you create a list of conversions and apply `Database.convertList` once to all.

Comment: Hi Pauline, I agree with Phil W: We need the error message :-) And are you sure the thing is "failing on the line where I assign email to lead"? This is even before you insert the leads, - before any lead related trigger is executed. (And it is very unlikely, because it would appear the executing user has no access to the Email field, which is implausible in a test context.) Do you mean "failing _due_ to the line..."?

Comment: Thanks @PhilW I have updated the post with the error message.

Comment: I just found out that the convertLead does upto 100 records. Now i see there is a flow causing it to fail.